# jQuery.fn.addClass resets after clicking on a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.menu li a").click(function(e){
        $("a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div>                   
    <ul id="top_bookmarks" class="menu list-inline">
        <li><a class="selected" href="/56">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href="/64">item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It works, but when i click on item 2 class "selected" is added only for one second and then it's removed and added back to item 1.

How i can fix it?

Comment: That's because the anchors are followed and a new page is loaded, what did you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the second li -> anchor tag, then check the url. The data is sent via the url and the page reloads and hence resets the page and hence your class.

If you want to stop the page reload, and want to stay on the same page, then you can use event.preventDefaul() method on the click of the anchor. In your case it would be `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However when i use preventDefault() it works fine but a href doesnt work. How i can keep added classes after page reload?

Comment: preventDefault will prevent the default action. What you intend to achieve?

Comment: Let's say i have two a href's Item 1 and Item 2. I want to highlight currently clicked a href with "selected" CSS class after page reloads. Example: http://i.imgur.com/vWmlScZ.png

Comment: after page reloads? This means you want to navigate to some different page where you have the same dom elements -> div and then add the class to the selected item?

Comment: Nevermind, i used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999501/bootstrap-3-keep-selected-tab-on-page-refresh  Thanks anyway!