# Auto Select Tab on Page Navigation

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, razor, tabs, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view that contains a Twitter Bootstrap `nav nav-pills` control. This is embedded fine, and in each of my tabs I am planning to embed two partial views. Below is the razor view

```
@using SiteNET.Models;
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
@model SiteNET.Models.ManageUserViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Account";
}
<style type="text/css">
    .manage {
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
<div class="manage">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#manage">Manage Account</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#downloads">Avalible Downloads</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="manage" class="tab-pane active fade in">
            <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
            <p class="text-success">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</p>
            @*<div class="alert alert-success"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            role="alert">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</div>*@
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.Partial("_ChangeEmailAddressPartial", Model)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @if (ViewBag.HasLocalPassword)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_SetPasswordPartial")
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            @section Scripts {
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
            }
        </div>
        <div id="downloads" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Downloads</h3>
            <p>Avalible downloads partial view.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the page loads the content of the first tab is shown but the actual tab is not selected (see below)

[image: Not Selected First Tab]

it should look like this when the page is first loaded

[image: How it Should Look]

I have tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19015027/626442), which uses the JavaScript below

```
<script>
    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

    // Store the currently selected tab in the hash value
    $("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
        var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
        window.location.hash = id;
    });

    // On load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('#myTab a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
</script>
```

But this does not seem to work (that is, does not seem to select the first tab when the page is loaded). It also does not store the selected tab. How can I

1. Make the first tab show as selected when the page is first loaded?
2. How can I amend the JS above so that the selected tab is persisted between page navigations?

Thanks for your time.

---

To see this problem for your self go to [CodeLAB](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php) and paste in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Pills Nav with Icons</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    //$('#myTab a[href="manage"]').tab('show');
    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

    // Store the currently selected tab in the hash value
    $("ul#myTab > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
        var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
        window.location.hash = id;
    });

    //$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
    //    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    //    window.location.hash = id;
    //});

    // On load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('#myTab a[href="#' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
</script>
    <div class="manage">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab">
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#manage">Manage Account</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#downloads">Avalible Downloads</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="manage" class="tab-pane active fade in">
                <h2>Manage</h2>
                <p class="text-success">Success</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>Partial view A</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>Partial view B</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="downloads" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Downloads</h3>
                <p>Avalible downloads partial view.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then click "Show Output", you will see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with asp and whatsoever, but for the bootstrap / jQuery part I guess your solution is this:

1.) Give the `li` you want to be active the class `.active`. For example:

```
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#manage">Manage Account</a></li>
```

The same goes than for the according content element, like you already did.

```
<div id="manage" class="tab-pane active fade in">xxx</div>
```

Take a closer look to the according bootstrap documentation: [**Bootstrap Tabs**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

2.) I guess it's not working because your script targets the wrong element (`ul.nav-tabs`), which doesn't exist in your code. As far as I can see it from your code, you have `.nav-pills` instead. So try:

```
$("ul.nav-pills > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;
});
```

Or even better, try targeting your unique id `#myTab`, like this:

```
$("ul#myTab > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;
});
```

If this doesn't help or hint you in the right direction, please try to create a working fiddle of your generated html output so that we can take a closer look at your code.

**UPDATE**

Try this code. It works perfectly for me on my localhost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Pills Nav with Icons</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(location.hash) {
            $('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').tab('show');
        }
        $(document.body).on("click", "a[data-toggle]", function(event) {
            location.hash = this.getAttribute("href");
        });
    });
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
        var anchor = location.hash || $("a[data-toggle=tab]").first().attr("href");
        $('a[href=' + anchor + ']').tab('show');
    });
</script>
<div class="manage">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#manage">Manage Account</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#downloads">Avalible Downloads</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="manage" class="tab-pane active fade in">
            <h2>Manage</h2>
            <p class="text-success">Success</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Partial view A</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Partial view B</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="downloads" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Downloads</h3>
            <p>Avalible downloads partial view.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I have made the changes but these do not seem to help. I have updated the question with code you can paste into CodeLAB.

Comment: This works and selects the default tab item because of the `<li class="active">` not the scripting. The scripting I created to reinstate the selected tab when you nav. from and back to the page. This still does not work and I don't know why. However, I can live with the lack of reinstating the tab position so will accept your answer, thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Did you try the code in a blank html file on your server? Because the `location` changing doesn't work in online editors like codelab etc.. As I said, for me it works on my localhost..

Comment: I did try it in VS2013, but using the local database ("LocalDB"). I have not got this site on a server yet...