# Dynamic Bootstrap navigation with active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I have created my project on Bootstrap 3.3.6 now I am facing a problem with navigation whenever I clicked on any menu that will reset as it is, but I want to set it as active tab. The Same problem happens with the sidebar. How can I resolve it ?

Thank You

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li class="header">HEADER</li>
  <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
  <li class="active"><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Admin</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li><a href="setting.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Setting</a></li>
      <li><a href="adduser.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Add User</a></li>
      <li><a href="users.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Users</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make tab active by writing this line of code in click event of tab

$(this).addClass("active");

here You can find example

http://www.bootply.com/70331#

Comment: Yes, it will work, if you not reload the page on click. I think, here, this will be helpful [bootstrap-3-keep-selected-tab-on-page-refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999501/bootstrap-3-keep-selected-tab-on-page-refresh)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

**First (If your site is static)**

Just change the static class "active" on each page.
If you have three menus- one, two , three then you will set `class="active"` on all three subsequent pages you open.
Say for one you have `one.html` for two you have `two.html` then you have to add the classes as per the menu page and remove the class from last page element.

**Second (Through jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("PreviousElementName").removeClass("active");//removes last manu item class
  $('CurrentElement').addClass('active'); // adds new menu item class
});
```