# Keep active tab on page refresh in bootstrap 4 using local storage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, local-storage, bootstrap-4

I am trying to keep selected tab active on page refresh. but when i am not able to find any solution for tabs in bootstrap 4. i tried to make changes according to bootstrap 3 solutions but nothing work. please help me.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav my-nav1 nav-tabs mt-3 " id="myTab" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item border border-secondary rounded">
    <a class="nav-link active"  data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">MENU1</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item border border-secondary rounded">
   <a class="nav-link "  data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">MENU2</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

this is js i am using but it dosen't work.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
  });
  var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
  if(activeTab){
    $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
  }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You can make use of `localStorage`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999501/bootstrap-3-keep-selected-tab-on-page-refresh?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I tried solutions on stackoverflow but all solutions working with bootstrap 3 but when i tried with bootstrap 4 it dosen't work.

Comment: please someone give me solution for above code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3: Keep selected tab on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999501/bootstrap-3-keep-selected-tab-on-page-refresh)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The jQuery selector is wrong: `$('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]')`, it should be...

`$('.nav-tabs a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');`

https://www.codeply.com/go/C2B3mcrgSJ

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});

var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if(activeTab){
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfect for me. and also there is js that was causing problem. i changed js and it works perfect for me.

Comment: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-keep-the-current-tab-active-on-page-reload-in-bootstrap.php