# Traverse the navtags and stay on one of them

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a nav-tabs using bootstrap 3.3.7

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li><a href="#">Concept</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">Read</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
</ul>
```

Every time I click a tab, it's activated and others are deactivated,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        $(".nav-tabs li").on("click", function(){
            $(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }));
</script>
```

It works fine with code,

[image]

However, when I refreshed the page, all the tags `active` class are removed,

I want it stay on the clicked tag until another click is triggered.

Comment: I am not sure you can do this, you can manually set the active tab but you would have to store it as a cookie or something which would be messier

Comment: did not understand the issue here. Are you making point to make clicked tag active first and then make other tags inactive?

Comment: Refreshing the page resets all elements to the state, declared in the code. If you want to keep this active, you need to persist the data. There are many ways to do that so you should do some research on that. @JohnKane already pointed cookies as a possible option and there are many more including sessionStorage, localStorage, or simply using a server backend with database

Comment: possible Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999501/bootstrap-3-keep-selected-tab-on-page-refresh

Comment: @LoneWolf Looks deceiving but no. This doesn't have the option.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I think storing the selected tab in the hashvalue will work. On Clicking a tag with href, the window location automatically updates. In any case, the answer I shared will resolve OP's issue, why wouldn't it?

Comment: @LoneWolf But the OP doesn't have differentiating hashes... I have given a solution that doesn't change the HTML... :) Obviously it's dumb but...

Comment: I think adding differentiating hashes to the HTML would be an easy alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is on client side. And they do not persist. Either use `localStorage` or Cookies to achieve a persistent state, even after page reload.

Moreover, your code below won't work and throw an error. The **corrected code** is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-tabs li").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

So every time when a click event is made, **set the `localStorage`**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-tabs li").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    localStorage.setItem("active", $(this).text().trim());
  });
});
```

And when you load the page, **set the `active` class**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-tabs li").each(function () {
    if (typeof localStorage.getItem("active") != "undefined" && $(this).text().trim() == localStorage.getItem("active"))
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });
  $(".nav-tabs li").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    localStorage.setItem("active", $(this).text().trim());
  });
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-tabs li").each(function() {
    if (typeof localStorage.getItem("active") != "undefined" && $(this).text().trim() == localStorage.getItem("active"))
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });
  $(".nav-tabs li").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    localStorage.setItem("active", $(this).text().trim());
  });
});
```

```css
.active {font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <li><a href="#">Concept</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Read</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** StackSnippets don't allow `localStorage`. Please check output on: [**JSBin**](http://output.jsbin.com/pozifalepa).

Answer (score 1):

First add id to ur tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li id="concept"><a href="#">Concept</a></li>
    <li id="code"><a href="#">Code</a></li>
    <li id="read"><a href="#">Read</a></li>
    <li id="action"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(
        var cachedTabId = sessionStorage.getItem('selected-tab');
        if(cachedTab) $("#"+cachedTabId).addClass("active");
        $(".nav-tabs li").on("click", function(){
            $(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            sessionStorage.setItem('selected-tab', $(this).attr('id'));
        }));
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to keep your active tab cached even if the client close the browser's tab use **localStorage** instead of **sessionStorage**