# Refreshing bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for some help with bootstrap tabs.

I have bootstrap tabs with a panel and would like the tab open to remain upon refresh. We have a number of things going on but this is mostly needed as we have new data being inputted via NinjaForms.

Anyway. This is the solution i've found but I cannot get it to work, for some reason..

**TABS**

```
 <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="z-index:998;">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1overview" data-toggle="tab"><i 
class="fa fa-building" style="color:#50AE54"></i> Client Overview</a> . 
</li>
        <li><a href="#tab2sites" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa- 
sitemap" style="color:#1DB2C8"></i> Sites</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3users" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-user- 
plus" style="color:#FC5830"></i> Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4assets" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa- 
desktop" style="color:#2C98F0"></i> Assets</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-wrench" 
 style="color:#333333"></i> Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#tab11internal" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa 
 fa-wrench" style="color:#333333"></i> Internal Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab12external" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa 
 fa-wrench" style="color:#333333"></i> External Services</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-wrench" 
 style="color:#333333"></i> Web Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#tab6webhosting" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa 
 fa-wrench" style="color:#333333"></i> Web Hosting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab7domains" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa 
fa-wrench" style="color:#333333"></i> Domains</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab8crushftp" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa 
  fa-wrench" style="color:#333333"></i> SFTP</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa- 
    certificate" style="color:#333333"></i> Licenses <span 
   class="caret"></span> 
     </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#tab9email" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa- 
         certificate" style="color:#333333"></i> eMail</a></li>            
          </ul>
        </li>
           <li><a href="#tab10faq" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa- 
   question" style="color:#1DB2C8"></i> FAQ</a></li>
       <!-- Commented out for now <li><a href="#tab10migrations" data- 
     toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-rocket" style="color:#2C98F0"></i> 
     Migrations</a></li> -->
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});
var activeTab = window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if (activeTab) {
    $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    window.localStorage.removeItem("activeTab");
}
});
```

**WP Functions**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'tabs-refresh',  
get_template_directory_uri().'/library/js/tabs.js', array( 'jquery' ), 
'1.0.0', false );
```

Just to add, upon inspection of the console in Chrome. I have found this:

[Chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz2EC.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> By default when you enqueue jQuery in Wordpress you must use jQuery,
>   and $ is not used (this is for compatibility with other libraries).

See: [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

Make your function:

```
(function($){ 
   [...]
})(jQuery);
```

So:

```
(function($){ 
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});
var activeTab = window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if (activeTab) {
    $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    window.localStorage.removeItem("activeTab");
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected the JS issue but the tabs, upon being refreshed are still not staying on the selected tab.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999501/bootstrap-3-keep-selected-tab-on-page-refresh

Comment: Thanks i've tried these solutions but not working. The tabs don't "stay put"

Answer (score 0):

When you are using jquery along with WordPress, due to compatibility you must use `jQuery` and not `$`

If you want to use document.ready, you can pass $ into the function as a parameter:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  // Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out.

By simply added this to the tab;

```
 <li><a href="#tab11internal" **role="tab"** data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa- 
 wrench" style="color:#333333"></i> Internal Services</a></li>
```