# Property 'tab' does not exist on type 'JQuery'

Tags: jquery, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

**My Html Code is**

```
<nav class="nav-sidebar">
<ul class="nav tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active" ><a  href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" >Tabl 1</a> </li>                               
  <li class="tab2"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Tab 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**And in My .ts**

```
$('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).tab('show');
   });
   $("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
     var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
     window.location.hash = id;
   });
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   $('#myTab a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

Tried so many from stackoverflow and other web sites but i ended up with 'tab' doesn't exist in jquery

Comment: And from where did you find the documentation that says `.tab()` is a jquery function?

Comment: In terminal when we run 'npm start'

Answer (score 5):

You need to install [`@types/bootstrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're confusing `tab()` with `tabs()`.
Read more here: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: I'm Very Clear that both are different if you have any doubts you can check here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21494906/9266349

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not have a function `tab()`;

Maybe you should import a Expansion witch add a function `tab()` into jQuery！

And if you us UI framework, you need to introduce the corresponding resources！