# Keep a Tab or Tabs in the same position when clicking on a button -Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, bootstrap-4, datatables

I currently have a project that has tabs and within each tab has its respective table as shown in the image:

[image]

For this project I use Bootstrap tabs and for the tables I use DataTables.

```
 <nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> EMISOR</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false"><i class="fas fa-inbox"></i> RESPONSABLE</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="nav-admin-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-admin" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-admin" aria-selected="false"><i class="fas fa-toolbox"></i> ADMIN</a>                 
 </div>
</nav>
```

My problem or doubt is that in the **"APPROVAL"** column there is a button that when clicked changes the status to approved or vice versa.

```
@if ($task->stade == "0")
<a href="{{ url('/administrator/task/'.$task->id.'/stade ')}}" class="btn btn-warning ">
   &#9866;
</a>
@else
<a href="{{ url('/administrator/task/'.$task->id.'/stade ')}}" class="btn btn-success ">
  &#10003;
</a>
@endif
```

And this is my controller

```
public function geTaskstade($id){
$task = Task::findOrFail($id);
if($task->stade == "0"):
   $task->stade = "1";
   $msg = "Yes";
else:
   $task->stade = "0";
   $msg = "off";
endif;
if($task->save()):     
   return back()->with('message',$msg)->with('typealert','warning');
endif;}
```

I would like that when I click on the approval button it does not return to the main tab but stays in the one it was in.

Example: if I am in the administrator tab and I press the approve button it is sent but the page reloads and takes me to the sender tab I would like it to stay in the administrator tab when reloading.

When looking at the Bootstrap tabs I see that it has an **active** class, maybe I can make a function with JavaCcript that when clicking on **APPROVAL** does not change position, if so could anyone guide me on how to do it or another recommended way.

Comment: Bootstrap already has [JavaScript behavior](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#javascript-behavior) for tabs, [.tab(‘show’)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#tabshow) seems to be what you're looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I keep selected Bootstrap tab on page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18999501/12567365) - or also any of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+return+to+same+tab+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I will look at what is recommended

Answer (score 0):

there have been comments about how it can be done with Javascript, but I wanted to add a version made with php for this.

First of all, after the information is processed in the controller file, we need to send which tab will be open when we return. For example;

```
public function geTaskstade($id){
$task = Task::findOrFail($id);
if($task->stade == "0"):
$task->stade = "1";
$msg = "Yes";
$tab = 1;
else:
$task->stade = "0";
$msg = "off";
$tab = 2;
endif;
if($task->save()):     
return back()->with('message',$msg)->with('typealert','warning')->with('tab', $tab);
endif
;}
```

I add 'tab'.

Now we know which tab to open.

On the front side, we will change a class directly so that the relevant tab is open.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link @if(!session('tab') or (session('tab') and session('tab') == 1)) active @endif" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link @if(session('tab') and session('tab') == 2) active @endif" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade @if(!session('tab') or (session('tab') and session('tab') == 1)) show active @endif" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade @if(session('tab') and session('tab') == 2) show active @endif" id="profile-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
</div>
```

In this way, we have determined which tab will be open with the 'tab' information we send from the back. Hope it's helpful for someone.

Comment: your answer helped me as a guide to implement a solution I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, 

Can you edit the grammatically incorrect sentences so that other reviewers can better understand them? (My English is not good enough to explain some terms)